# Assistance selecting multiple ranges on different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get a macro to send an email with different ranges pasted into the body of the email

As you can see from the code below this successfully sends an email with the range selected to the intended people with the ranges I have selected at the bottom.

Now I need to try and change the

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B8:D304").Select
```

to also select a similar range on a different sheet "Ticket Tracker" and put that at the bottom, or wherever in the email.

I tried to search for the result myself, but couldn't find much for this that I could understand very well myself as I have never trained in .vba and have cobbled this together from basic information.

I tried the Union, but found that they do not affect multiple sheets.

```
Sub SendTrackerForEmails()

   ' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
   ActiveSheet.Range("B8:D304").Select

   ' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
   ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
   ' the To, CC and Subject lines.


   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = ""
      .Item.To = Range("F17").Value
      .Item.Subject = Worksheets("Splash Screen").Range("H10").Value & "'s 
Email Tracker Results"
      .Item.CC = Range("F26").Value & ";" & Range("H9").Value
   End With
End Sub
```

I expect the second range in "Ticket Tracker" to be placed into the email, although I am not sure how you would select this.

I have tried the below answer, but if you read the comments it causes an error message when trying to hide the errors.

Appears to be related to the fact the mail envelope is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decent get-around for this issue can be to:

1. insert a new sheet
2. paste the data from the 2 separate sheets on this new sheet
3. send the email from new sheet
4. then delete the new sheet.

See below:

```
Sub SendTrackerForEmails()

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet: Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ticketSheet As Worksheet: Set ticketSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ticket Tracker")

    ' insert a new sheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set newSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
    End With

    ' copy data from 2 sheets
    dataSheet.Range("B8:D304").Copy newSheet.Range("A1")
    ticketSheet.Range("B8:D304").Copy newSheet.Range("A300")

    ' Show the envelope on the Workbook
    newSheet.Activate
    ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
    ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
    ' the To, CC and Subject lines.
    With newSheet.MailEnvelope
        .Introduction = ""
        .Item.To = dataSheet.Range("F17").Value
        .Item.Subject = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Splash Screen").Range("H10").Value & "'s Email Tracker Results"
        .Item.CC = dataSheet.Range("F26").Value & ";" & dataSheet.Range("H9").Value
        .Send ' added this
    End With

    ' added this
    ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try, I did consider this option but wasn't too sure how to go around it.

I will give this a try next week and report back tyvm

Comment: Hi mate, I tried this and it sorta works.

However I noticed that the

         `Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        newSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

Appears to be deleting the sheet without the confirmation box, but whenever it runs that part it states the below

    `"Method 'Display Alerts' of object '_Application Failed' error`

Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that the issue might be related to the fact it doesn't wait for the email to be sent? As I noticed that if I removed the 'Application.DisplayAlerts' it would ask me to delete the sheet before I had sent the email?

Comment: @InvkrMainr hey so I added the `.Send` of the email and also hid the Envelope after sending, check out the edits above